# Firefox and Opera not adding active class based on viewpoint

Tags: jquery, firefox, scroll, anchor, opera

Hello there fellow developers!

I'm experiencing a problem I just can't solve, mainly because my konwledge about javascript is limited.

Here is an example: http://funkypixels.lv/scroll-problem/
Nothing too fancy here - just sliding between blocks with a class="current" being applied to the list menu!
Now go on and click that link which leads to a page with a link+anchor which leads back to the index.html and should highlight the third menu

. This works on Chrome and IE9 but not on Firefox and Opera. On Firefox/Opera that class is applied only when I scroll the page a bit.

I have tried several other plug-ins and they all have the same issue on Firefox/Opera!

The jquery.nav.js has an issue with IE9 but since all other plug-ins I tried, failed on Firefox/Opera there seems to be something wrong with the idea on what these type of plug-ins are based on.

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me or point out what is the problem and how it should be solved!

---

PS.

A stupid idea that would probably solve this would be to jerk the page 1px vertically on load but then the question is - scroll to where? And how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The script is written to check for scroll events and update the navigation while page is being scrolled, so I'm not surprised you see this effect. You may want to report an issue to the script's author here:

http://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav

A suitable way to fix it might be to listen not only to scroll but also to hashchange events and update the navigation style accordingly.